# Intellij IDEA custom Auto-Completion

Tags: lua, intellij-idea

I would like to get an auto-completion on IntelliJ Idea...
I am learning moaiSDK which is based on Lua. I already setup the Lua plugins within Idea and have a working lua environment.
Now I would like to have also the Moai API's on Idea. I see there are HTML docs here: http://getmoai.com/docs/index.html , but having no experience on this field I don't if it's doable and how.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of [this Moai post](http://getmoai.com/forums/moai-sdk-for-intellij-idea-t445):

http://getmoai.com/forums/moai-sdk-for-intellij-idea-t445

Using plandem's 'moai-api.zip' (includes **) and [Sylvanaar2's IntelliJ Lua plugin](https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Setting_Up_Custom_API%27s), you should be able to get what you're looking for.

Happy coding!

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 2):

I was using IntelliJ with Lua with some autocompletion, but, this just got release and supports MOAI out of the box.

http://studio.zerobrane.com/

So far, its GREAT.  I think you gonna enjoy this one better. ;)

Answer (score 1):

[This post shows](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/08/22/Setting-up-an-IDE-IntelliJ-IDEA-with-auto-completion-for-MOAI-game-development.aspx) how to configure IntelliJ IDE to do Moai auto-completion ( and more ) in extreme detail.